# Zero inflation formulas do not improve zero inflated model (GLMM)

Tags: mixed-model, glmm, count-data, zero-inflation, glmmtmb

I'm a student trying to adjust a count data GLMM to zero inflation using function glmmTMB.

Model family is nbinom1 family (better AICc compared to nbinom2 and poisson).
My data contains about 20 % zeros and I consider the zeros true zeros due to low abundance of individuals.

The ratio predicted/observed zeros stays 0.25, no matter if i add a ziformula and which ziformula. I add formulas to the model by adding "ziformula=~a", a being different respective fixed effects of the model. AICc is better for the model without ziformulas (lower AICc).

How should I deal with the situation? Can I go on without adding a ziformula?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You are not assessing the presence of a "zero-inflation effect" properly. Calling zeroes true vs fake sort of makes sense thinking that you may want to interpret the conditional non-zero-inflated part of a model - suppose for instance you're modeling monthly skiing-related accidents, whereas May through October there's no snow at all on which to ski. But the point is: you can't say, because there's 10% zeroes or 20% zeroes or even 50% zeroes, that a model is zero inflated.

For instance, a Poisson($\lambda=1$) random variable will have $\exp(-1) \approx 37\%$ zeroes. You can check if the mean $\hat{\lambda}$ from a Poisson or NB model is at or below the value required to produce a certain number of zeroes. For instance, with 20% zeroes, you'd expect an average $\lambda$ of about 1.6 in a Poisson model.

An analytic solution may not be possible with negative binomial so illustrating a numeric solution:

```
> uniroot(function(x) dpois(0, x) - 0.2, interval = c(0.1, 2))
$root
[1] 1.609438
```

I'm curious how you evaluated the "expected" number of zeroes with your model for the non-zero inflated part. If the ratio is 25%, then the zero inflation only accounts for 5% of the zeroes in your sample, and the other 15% would be explained by very low intensity count process that are likely to be 0, but the actual intensities would be non-zero, low like 0.1 even, but not zero.

Anyway, a ratio of zeroes is a way of assessing calibration, but usually models evaluated internally show calibration. So, no matter what you use (zero inf or non) I would expect the model to show good calibration if you assess it correctly. To the broader question of: how do I detect zero-inflation? The suggestion to use an IC seems reasonable, and so you should just compare the fits with AIC.